# Everyone believes everything Joe says. How can he get around it?

Tags: society, super-powers

Joe is an average bloke, who has a passive superpower that he's lived with all his life.

People believe everything he says. Implicitly, unquestioningly and absolutely. If he says that black is actually neon purple, people within earshot accept that as a natural truth. If he then recanted his statement then black would be black again.

This has certain advantages ('But this meal is on the house, waiter!'), but Joe wants to live a normal life (for a variety of reasons, one of which is evil assassins).

How can Joe avoid accidentally using his superpower in everyday life given that even seemingly innocuous statements like 'Good Morning' can completely change the mental state of those around him?

Joe can't turn this power off, and wants to be able to live as a normal western adult male, so taking a vow of silence or retiring to the Rockies in a tent aren't options.

**Edit:**
For the avoidance of doubt: This applies only to spoken and heard communications (the deaf are immune). On the other hand: For the purpose of combinations such as pointing and speaking, anything that someone would think to themselves 'that's obviously a lie' when it's said/done by non-Joe, believes it implicitly when it's said/done by Joe. If the person has misheard or misconstrued what Joe said, then they implicitly believe what they heard/understood, not what Joe intended. If what Joe says just doesn't make sense (for example: Patent explosive donkey muffin discombobulate.) then confusion is the response that will occur, not attempting to parse the sentence into 'truth'.

Now I want a Patent explosive donkey.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32934/discussion-on-question-by-joe-bloggs-everything-joe-says-is-true-how-can-he-get).

Comment: This is almost the plot for `The invention of lying`: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1058017/

Comment: I also think you need to come up with a reason why he shouldn't use it for his own good. No-one will know, he can gain a lot of power, he will have to continue to choose between own benefit and honesty. What is his motivation? Even the good guy will cave in eventually.

Comment: What if he said, "What I am saying is not true."? or even "From now on, what I am saying might be or might not be true." and just keep saying that until everyone hears that.

Comment: I'm actually kind of disappointed. Based on the title I thought this would be a "Lathe of Heaven"-esque ability. Looks more like Kilgrave though.

Comment: @Martijn: See the note about evil assassins? There ya go. :D

Comment: @nukeforum: You can get into all sorts of trouble with that. Mostly by saying 'Nothing I say is true', which causes not just a linguistic but a very real and unsolvable paradox!

Comment: @JoeBloggs Yes, but that could be the preventative. Maybe the only thing he can't do is create a paradox. He just has to speak in paradox at all times! :)

Comment: @JoeBloggs I think only the first evil assassin would be dangerous. If Joe gets a chance to talk to him/her, he can say "You shouldn't kill me. In fact, you should help me to talk to all the other assassins."

Comment: You're going to stop thinking about this question.

Comment: @Martijn You beat me to it :)) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invention_of_Lying

Comment: I have many clarification questions since this feels incomplete to me (at least in your post). Is it jsut limited to the stuff he is saying? If so just writing would be a solution for him or designing an language not expressed through voice. If so, is it important that the people understand the language he is speaking in; if not so what would happen if he says for example "look over there" *pointing on a bird* "thats, a car" Would it matter what they are seeing or what joe meant to point at? all this are not unimportant aabilitys of the treat that might alter the answer one oculd give.

Comment: A slight aside: "Good morning" isn't a statement, it's a wish. It's a contraction of "I wish you a good morning".

Comment: Related comic: [Pinocchio on SMBC](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3730)

Comment: @Zaibis some good questions, I'd second them. No need to design a non-oral language though, plenty to be going on with. Depending on your interpretation, this clause is pretty magical: "If he says that black is actually neon purple, people within earshot accept that..." If he says something in, say, American Sign Language, would the profoundly deaf ASL speaker watching him be unaffected, not having any "earshot" to speak of?

Comment: The character King Leck in Kristin Cashore's Graceling trilogy has this superpower, and she does an *excellent* job of portraying his power and the chaos he can cause around him. Unlike your Joe though, he's absolutely evil!

Comment: Can't he just tell someone "The world realises that Joe doesn't always tell the truth" ?

Comment: One fun side-effect of Joe's powers would be the significantly better-than-average appearance of anyone in regular contact with Joe due to white-lies becoming true. "How do I look in this outfit?".

Comment: If he said: "Do not believe me" will it then activated his hidden superpower and turn into a blackhole and swallows the earth? If not then what are you doing with your life?

Comment: Does recorded/re-broadcast voice count?  For example, if Joe decided to be a TV or Radio personality, would it affect anyone within "earshot" of any speaker reproducing his voice?  Or is it only his "actual" voice that has this effect?  How about something like a megaphone?  Or his voice-mail greeting message? Or a microphone on a stage performance, etc?

Comment: Just tell the evil assassins that you're harmless and there's really no reason to kill you. Since they believe you, they'll go away.

Comment: Does someone go insane if Joe tells them 2+2=5?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Just tell the truth - and be specific.**

Joe's superpower appears to be a problem in one of two types of situations:

1. He says something that isn't true ("I am a green stegosaurus!").
2. He says something that could be interpreted in different ways ("Good morning!").

Joe can control things in the first case by simply always telling the truth. I can't think of many situations in which this would be problematic - most of us don't claim to be dinosaurs on a daily basis - except in ones where he might have to tell white lies. Lying then won't cause huge problems.

Besides, there are situations where having people believe white lies could be handy. For example, Joe Jr. will finally believe his dad when he's told that that red liquid isn't the actor's blood, but ketchup.

The second case can be averted by saying an entire sentence. For example, people say "Good morning!" to one another as a greeting. If you make this a full sentence, though, it can be thought of in different ways:

- "I hope you have a good morning!"
- "I think it is a good morning!"
- "It *is* a good morning!"

All Joe has to do is be specific as to which of these he means.

Comment: I think of the options this is the most sensible and least likely to cause further complications. Though his speech patterns will become quite affected.

Comment: Or imperative. "Have a nice day". Since it's not declarative, it's not something that would be believed.

Comment: @JoeBloggs It probably won't break his normal-western-adult-male-ness…but maybe, just maybe, he'll be remembered for a while as that one guy who always worded things just a little bit funny.

Comment: If Joe said "Good morning" to me, it wouldn't affect me. When I hear someone say "Good morning," I don't understand it as any kind of statement of fact, but just a form of "Hello" that you say before noon. I suspect the majority of people feel the same way. (Till I read this thread, it never occurred to me that anyone would take "Good morning" as a statement, instead of a greeting.)

Comment: *Joe Jr. will finally believe his dad when he's told that that red liquid isn't the actor's blood, but ketchup.* - Could have negative consequences, as when someone tells Joe Jr. 'Oh, they used fake blood for this scene' he will be immovable in the belief that it's ketchup, even when presented with logical evidence, making him a mockery to the other people.

Comment: Imagine if a student had Joe's superpower... can he "lie" on paper?

Comment: @SGR Actually, if Joe says `Oh, they used fake blood for this scene` then the past changes so it IS actually keptchup what they used in that scene; so joke's on the other people...

Comment: When taken as an absolute truth, "I hope you have a good morning!" is not the same as "Good morning!" the former makes the listener believes that Joe is wishing him a good morning from all his heart which implies personal interest or creepiness instead of it being a simple greeting. "Greetings" on the other hand does not imply personal interest.

Comment: I'm disappointed that not one of you has mentioned Gandalf's exploration of the phrase "Good morning" in Hobbit.

Comment: @Mark "Do you wish me a good morning, or mean that it is a good morning whether I want it or not; or that you feel good this morning; or that it is a morning to be good on?" -Gandalf the Grey (Already had this copied when I saw your comment, lol)

Answer (score 88):

He could train himself to turn every statement into a question: "Good morning, isn't it?"

Comment: Another possibility would be to start every statement with "I think". Like "I think this will be a great day."

Comment: This is how Kilgrave tries to "be normal" w/ Jessica in *Jessica Jones*; he consciously avoids ever making declarative statements to her, but couches everything in questions and interpretations.

Comment: Good morning, isn't it? Though phrased as a question, it effectively a statement with a request to affirm the statement.

Comment: What if the questions were open-ended interrogatives, phrased as: "How do you feel about the weather?"

Comment: @GaryWalker true, but the superpower implementation may not know about it.

Comment: I think it might be possible for someone to interpret this as "I do believe this is a good morning. What are your thoughts on this?". There, they may be forced to agree with what he believes in anyway. Just a possibility.

Comment: @Javelin: "I do believe this is a good morning" is a statement about his believes, not about the morning. Therefore in this case the only thing someone would be forced to agree with would the that *Joe believes* this is a good morning. So if someone told him "Joe doesn't actually think the morning is good" then he would violently disagree. While he may still think the morning isn't good (and possibly wonder why Joe considers this a good morning).

Comment: A similar answer to a similar problem: http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3730

Comment: I like this answer most, because it makes it easy for Joe to avoid mistakes.  It's a simple rule.  Always remembering to tell the exact truth and be extremely specific is more error-prone.

Answer (score 54):

**Joe should go into politics.**

The shock of having an honest politician may be a bit much, but people would accept it. After all its "Honest Joe". I have to admit, that I am assuming his superpower works over television, etc. and does not work only in his personal presence.

Joe is no longer accidentally using his superpower. He is using it intentionally to change the world for the better (hopefully).

As for his public policy speeches. He should be utterly dependent upon the teleprompter so that his words are carefully scripted to have the exact effect he desires.

In private he can instruct his advisors, etc. to tell me what you really think, don't worry about disagreeing with me. In fact he could get the best and brightest to advise him specifically about how to best use his superpower.

When caught in an impromptu press conference, etc. He could still control the message in acceptable ways. To dodge a question about current events, "I am not sure we know all of the relevant facts at this time but I am following the events and share your concern, next question please." or "I am not taking questions on this subject at this time" or "I don't have time to answer this right now" Best thing is, since even the reporters trust Joe, no controversial followup questions will trouble him.

Politics is about messaging. How do you say something to accentuate your message and not "step in it". Pick abortion as a an example, few things are more politically controversial in the US.

- As a Democrat: "I think abortion should be rare but legal. But
  ultimately at some level it is wrong to force a woman in what has to
  be a very personal decision."
- As a Republican: "I think abortion should only be legal in very
  restricted cases. Although I am very sympathetic to the women
  carrying an unwanted child, I cannot agree that killing an innocent
  baby is something a moral people can endorse."

I believe both of these statements are a pretty accurate representation of the party positions. Coming from Joe, both statements are perceived as reasonable by everybody. Coming from Hillary Clinton or Ted Cruz, they aggravate the opposition as wrong-headed and hypocritical.

Joe can memorize the stock phrases he needs to answer most questions to convey his precise intent. He can deal with other question using his dodge phrases until a better opportunity to answer carefully arises.

Now, if Joe is good and wise, we can have the best politician possible. If he is evil or foolish it could be very bad for his constituents.

If you have a superpower and don't use it you are simply wasting an opportunity. This waste will very likely eat at you as a failure of character (if good) or failure to take advantage (if evil). Avoiding the power will cause Joe harm, and logically if Joe is good, harm others by not having the benefit of his beneficence.

---

I thought that some people would not consider the life of a politician to be normal, but did not address it. I know some politicians personally. They seem to lead what is a very normal life. They love their spouse and kids, enjoy their kids and friends. Maybe they go to a ball game occasionally including their kids playing sports.

Perhaps at the level of the President of the US you are necessarily more isolated and thus not living a normal life. So maybe Joe will not run for the top office, maybe he limits his office to mayor of a large city.

On the other hand, if you get used to being mayor, maybe governor seems normal. And once you get used to being governor, becoming president seems normal. I know I've had this conversation with one of my politician friends and this is pretty much how he described it -- i.e., initially he was more impressed with the office and its responsibilities, but after a while it was just normal and the other senators no longer seemed above him in terms of being beyond just normal people like him.

---

I considered other professions, but eventually decided upon politician.

- Preacher
- Salesman
- Trial Lawyer
- Mediator
- News Anchor
- Public Relations
- Inspirational Speaker

All of these would certainly be different with Joe's condition. I would certainly welcome a careful case for any of the above for being a better choice or something that I did not consider.

Comment: Ah - yes. Going into politics, particularly in the US, would provide a useful counter to his superpower. Although everyone at his rallies would believe him, as soon as they walked away they go, "Wait? What?!? Why, that lying bastard...!" and he'd be free from his power/curse. Of course, he'd also stand a fair chance of being assassinated, but y'know - life is like that sometimes... :-)

Comment: If Joe said something it would be perceived as a natural truth. When you walk away you don't repudiate a natural truth. He may well be assassinated though, there are crazy people out there.

Comment: Fantastic idea. Not just convincing voters, but being able to meet your enemies and say " you really want to be friends" or "signing this deal is in your best interests".

Comment: I think this might be completely counter to being the "Average Joe" that asker asked for.

Comment: I thought it was a fresh viewpoint for resolving his problem.

Comment: `If you have a superpower and don't use it you are simply wasting an opportunity.`  True, and for this reason I think that if Joe becomes a Politician he will ultimately rise to the position of Absolute Benevolent(?) Dictator, Loved by All, Defender of Truth.

Comment: @BobJarvis I don't get all this talk of assassination.  A politician of all people has plenty of opportunity to be heard by any potential assassin talking about how you *simply don't kill or in any way seek to harm your leaders and in fact go out of your way to do your part to ensure their enduring good health and unending reign.*

Comment: Woah. A totalitarian. He would be very evil to use his powers for politics. `Now, if Joe is good and wise, we can have the best politician possible` --only if you don't like democracy :-/

Comment: What happens when people who heard Joe's lies talk about them to other people? The truth (the truly true truth, not the not really true, untruey truth) will get out

Comment: A normal, very, very successful life.. Unless the power goes to his head!

Comment: Guys, this isn't an interesting answer, because it is already happening.  EDIT: Nevermind, this is from 5 years ago.  I think Joe (Bloggs) super power is prophecy.

Answer (score 30):

### Learn [a sign language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_language) and never speak.

Since this uses manual communication we evade the fact that:

> People believe everything he says.

This strongly reduces accidental triggers of his superpower.

He would still need to talk to get proof that he's disabled (mute) by stating that fact to the necessary people (health specialists like nurses & doctors). With this proof he can then request official assistance (like requiring a dedicated translator for when he's following a meeting or symposium), which should strengthen his cover.

Comment: I think the OP excludes that with "doesn't want to take a vow of silence". I think it's probably his best bet, though.

Comment: This was the idea I had as well. Nice to see someone already thought of it. Communicating via sign language is something plenty of otherwise normal people (whatever that means) do.

Comment: This just changes the problem domain. A more generic answer might be "learn a different language", which doesn't seem terribly useful? The subtext here might be "learn a language with fewer speakers", but the logical conclusion there is quite similar to a vow of silence, i.e., unable to communicate.

Comment: @Ahriman I think we differ in our use/understanding of words! You open with, "Learn sign language and never speak", which seems like a non-starter to me - why learn a sign language but never speak it? Indistinguishable from a vow of silence. Unrelated: what's a disability proof and why does he need it? I can access a range of courses for my local sign language with relatively minimal barriers (money, mostly).

Comment: @Ahriman I tend to adopt a looser approach to the language you're using - it's not uncommon to find written language expressed as, e.g., "he [said/spoke/talked] in his diary". In my social context this pattern is commonly extended to signed languages. It's all down to interpretation though, and yours is just as valid! On a public service note - could you make it clearer there is more than one sign language in your answer (e.g. "Learn _a_ sign language...")? I can think of several interpreters who would thank you!

Comment: Deaf person here. With family and friends I talk in a local Signed Language (not ASL). I find your solution very clever. However first, the super power will now work on Deaf people. In other words, your answer is discriminating and offensive. I think you should acknowledge this and apologize to the Deaf people. Then second, amend the title to: «... and never speak orally». After all Joe will still be speaking, just a Signed Language. Take care!

Answer (score 16):

All Joe needs to do is say "I will never accidentally use my superpower," and he won't.

Comment: This assumes the superpower works on himself.

Comment: Since the original post does just says that "people" always believe him, and Joe is undoubtedly a person, that seems a reasonable assumption.

Comment: This seems to assume his powers have some reality-warping ability, when it just changes what people believe. If he believes he'll never accidentally use it... that doesn't stop him _actually_ accidentally using it _all the time,_ he just believes he won't ever do it. "Good morning!" - powers activate. Joe to himself: "Wait, did I just use my powers? Oh, hold on, of course not, ha ha, I can never use those accidentally."

Comment: @doppelgreener I think that would actually be a good answer.  The question is from Joe's perspective - he doesn't want to be a terrible person by mind-controlling everyone around him....  maybe his solution is to use his power to convince himself he's not.  It sucks for the people around him, sure, but Joe's happy.  Until and unless he gets assassinated, but depending on the reach of his power (i.e. through media), he could just put a comment on a really popular YouTube channel "You want to upvote this comment.  You never want to harm Joe Average of Averageville." before he "retires".

Comment: Doesn't work. His believing it doesn't make it true either.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, since this basically parallels the climax of *Ella Enchanted.*

Answer (score 12):

To avoid turning anyone to his point of view, Joe should never express opinions as facts but only as an opinion which applies to him personally.

Example:

*"<strike>Strawberry ice cream tastes disgusting</strike> Strawberry ice cream tastes disgusting **to me**."*

Someone hearing this won't be convinced that strawberry ice cream is disgusting to *everyone*, they will only be convinced that it is disgusting to Joe specifically. Their *personal* opinion about strawberry ice cream won't change.

Another option for Joe would be to counter his ability by constantly injecting statements into his everyday speech which tell the listener that he isn't trustworthy.

Example:

*"Strawberry Icecream is disgusting, but you know I don't have a common taste. We should buy something else, but you should not trust me on this. Why not buy chocolate ice cream instead? But remember, I am a liar."*

This way of speaking might seem unnatural to an unaffected person, but those affected by his ability might not notice it. Still, Joe will have to careful balance the use of these statements. Too much, and the person will start to develop a subconscious impression that Joe is not trustworthy and feel an aversion to him. Not enough, and he will start controlling people. It will take decades of practice until Joe finds the right balance. But over time this strange manner of speaking might become second nature to him.

---

Still, the ability to convince everyone he is speaking the truth and completely override their personal sense of reason is practically mind control. It is a very powerful ability which is very easy to abuse. Joe would have to possess an overwhelming amount of self-control and an extraordinary sense for morale and ethics to not get corrupted by this power. This is something people aren't born with. So he would have required a strong authority figure in his youth to get him on the right path. If he was born with his power, no such figure could have existed in his life, unless they were immune to his ability.

Comment: With your 2nd example, you just convinced the other person that you are a liar. Perhaps not what you wanted to accomplish. You know Joe is a liar, though you can't recall any example of Joe having lied.

Comment: What if it was actually a common taste in vicinity? That'd mean Joe just altered people perception which he didn't want to.

Comment: "Joe should never express opinions as facts but only as an opinion which applies to him personally." Furthermore, he should always express facts as opinions. He should get used to prefacing everything he says with "I believe that", "In my opinion", "I thought that", "it was my understanding that". In this way he will only convince people that he believes the things he's saying rather than convincing them to believe it too.

Answer (score 5):

Joe should say a paradox (such as "this sentence is false"), smile, and walk off.

Then we'll find out how super Joe's superpower is =)

Edit: For those who are not familiar with what a paradoxical statement is, its one which cannot possibly be true because it contradicts itself.  Thus his statement could not be true.  A paradox would be one of many places where Joe an test regions where his superpower cannot go.  It may, in fact, destroy his ability completely!

Comment: Not an answer...

Comment: @TimB Are you sure its not an answer?  How would people continue to believe everything he says is true once he has said a paradox?

Comment: Well that is why I flagged it rather than mod deleting. You don't explain why a paradox might turn it off or why the effect might last til next time he sees them...

Comment: When Joe makes a paradoxical statement it could turn people insane because they can't stop thinking about how to interpret it.

Comment: @Philipp You're assuming a more-than-usual attention to detail and need for logical consistency on the part of Joe's audience.

Comment: @Philipp I could actually see that as a side effect.  Honestly, this process nearly drove several mathematicians mad in the early 1900's.  I suppose that's the boobie prize of using the paradox approach: it either works, or it works by driving everyone too mad to understand true from false!

Comment: @CortAmmon - Mathematicians start off half mad. It seems to me that people might consider this a rhetorical falsehood. They know Joe is telling the truth, but since this statement cannot/must be true it means Joe  is using the paradox as a rhetorical device of some sort. This is an easier, non mind-breaking resolution to the paradox. Conflict resolving justifications don't necessarily make sense, but they do make it easier to live with the conflict.

Comment: I don't think people necessarily have problems with paradoxes. I mean, do you believe that sentence is true? If not, what's wrong with believing it is false? I mean, it can't be true, so it is false, right? It even says that in the sentence itself, after all! Easy to believe it is true that the sentence is false. And when that fails, there's always https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance

Comment: Alice laughed. "There's no use trying," she said: "one can't believe impossible things."
"I daresay you haven't had much practice," said the Queen. "When I was your age, I always did it for half-an-hour a day. Why, sometimes I've believed as many as six impossible things before breakfast."

Comment: @CodesInChaos Touche! =D

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be pretty hard, if not impossible, to live a normal life unless he can figure out what his weakness is and neutralize his own power.

It's pretty close to an absolute power over others, which would corrupt just about anyone.

Few things he could try, like shouting himself hoarse and see if it still works.
Breath helium or sulfur hexafluoride and test it.
Try it while connected to a MRI or other brain scan and see if a specific area lights up.

Worse case join the CIA and use the power to eliminate ISIS and other threats by simply telling them that killing is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

He could become a reporter. Then he can truthfully tell all the lies he wants to - or has to - accurately reporting the words of others, with appropriate attribution.

I heard some amusing examples of this happening, listening to Radio Moscow during the "glasnost" era and the fall of the Soviet Union.
During the Gorbachev era they were trying to learn new ways of reporting the news - and I think, actually making an honest effort not to be pure Soviet propaganda...

(One story of that time was about the Hungarian police having to give up their faithful Ladas ... all the crooks had BMWs...)

Then one morning came the big news story (on the BBC) that Gorbachev had been deposed by the hard liners, so I wondered what Radio Moscow's take would be, and I heard ... solemn classical music. Just the music... Then, and for the next few days, they reported official statements, attributed to the Politburo.

It was clearly impossible for them to voice any dissenting opinion : on the other hand, they would be negligent if they didn't report what the American president said about the situation ... so that's what they did - attributed to him, of course.

Three days later, when the hard liner's coup collapsed, they were finally able to report about the tanks parked in their back yard for the duration...

Comment: Yep, I'm sure he could be successful as a reporter or politician. However the question asked how he could live a normal life. Wouldn't this make his life even more complicated? If he says one wrong thing then it will affect thousands

Comment: Joe saying 'Gangnam style is the best song ever!' in this context would explain an awful lot.

Answer (score 2):

This answer tackles precisely what you've suggested in your question - How can Joe cope by with living a life where anything he says becomes -> true.

**What his power does:**

His power essentially makes things true. Whenever he says something is X, then, even if something is Y, it becomes X, and thus it's true.

**How to circumvent this power?**

He deconstructs sentences. Wishing someone good morning, an happy birthday, a good life, etc.. are easily prevented. "Good Morning" can be a statement, and thus using his power, however "I hope you're having a Good Morning"/"I wish you an happy birthday" wouldn't be using his power, as he's expressing something that affects him, and him alone, at least, regarding his powers (you could argue that wishes could come true due to a 3rd party).

Then there's arguments. Whenever he has to express an opinion, he would force others automatically to accept his opinion, wouldn't he?

He wouldn't. Once again, check out what the power does. People believe whatever he says. "The box is purple" would be an assertive statement which would make people believe that the box is indeed purple, however, "I believe the box is purple" would also trigger his powers, but instead of making people believe that the box is purple, it would make people believe that Joe thinks the box is purple.

In sum, he can live an happy life if he sticks to referring to himself whenever he talks, "I think", "I wish", "I would" are three statements that would allow him to live a normal life.

BUT... He won't be able to use sarcasm at all.

Comment: "however "I hope you're having a Good Morning"/"I wish you an happy birthday" wouldn't be using his power" -- Even statements like that would affect some people--the type of cynic who believes that people are so selfish that all good wishes for other people are insincere. They might say, "Oh my gosh, Joe is the first person who ever wished me a happy birthday without secretly wanting me to die in agony!"

Answer (score 1):

Well why don't he just tell people :

> I am not always telling the truth, and you got to use your own opinion to determine whether I am right or wrong.

He then just have to never disprove this sentence and this should go well.

Comment: I don't think this would work. The next sentence Joe says, the listener will automatically believe it true and also believe (because of this sentence) that  he/she has decided on his/her own.
Remember: Joe's power makes people **believe** what he says is true, but it doesn't make it true.

Answer (score 0):

So the deaf are immune. (And apparently assassins.) Is Joe himself immune? Could he with self-hypnosis or a helpful hypnotist convince himself it was simply a coincidence that everyone agreed with him? Isn't what he wants "a normal life" merely the illusion of a normal life? Perhaps once a week he tells himself in the mirror "I am just like everyone else" until he rediscovers his superpower by observation. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

One thing he could do is to state everything in terms of hearsay.  Instead of saying "coffee is good for you" he could say "I heard them say on TV that coffee is good for you".  Instead of "the price of gold is going up", he could say "My broker thinks the price of gold is going up".  And so on.  Thus Joe is not using his own magical credibility, but allowing the listener to judge by the credibility of the attributed author of each statement.